# Dependency injection data model in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm very new to FastAPI. I have a request which looks something like this:

```py
@router.post("/", response_model=EducationInResp)
async def create_Education_account(
        education_in: EducationCreation,
        current_user=Depends(get_current_user),
        has_perm=Depends(user_has_create_perms),
):
```

Now, the `EducationCreation` data model has a field called `customer_id`. I want to check if the `customer_id` exists in the database. Now, I know that I can manually do that within the function itself and it is not recommended to do database related validation in `Schema`. Is there any way to check if the `customer_id` exists in the database using `dependencies`? Is there something like this:

```py
async def check_customer_exist(some_val):
    # some operation here to check and raise exception

@router.post("/", response_model=EducationInResp)
async def create_Education_account(
        education_in: EducationCreation = Depends(check_customer_exist),
        current_user=Depends(get_current_user),
        has_perm=Depends(user_has_create_perms),
):
```

Comment: Yes you can do it. You'll need be able to access the customer fields in the  `check_customer_exists` function and either raise an `HTTPException` or return the data of type `EducationCreation`

Comment: How to access the `customer id` in `check_customer_exists`?  if the `check_customer_exists` has any param, it raises 422 and says that the value is missing. @isabi

Comment: Chris's was faster than me at responding and provided the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that by declaring the parameter in the dependency function, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455768/17865804). If the `customer_id` exists in the database, then return the data to the endpoint. If not, you could then raise an [`HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-httpexception), or handle it as desired.

### Example

```py
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException

customer_ids = [1, 2, 3]


async def check_customer_exists(ec: EducationCreation):
    # check if the customer_id exists in the database.
    if ec.customer_id not in customer_ids:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Customer ID not found")
    else:
        return ec


@router.post("/")
async def create(ec: EducationCreation = Depends(check_customer_exists)):
    pass
```

If you would like specifying global dependencies for every endpoint in the `router`/`app` instance and would like to pass data from dependencies to the endpoint, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) on how to do that.