# "AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'get'" when using Depends in FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, fastapi, depends

To implement authentication for a FastAPI endpoint, I want to make use of the `Depends` functionality offered in the latest versions (>=0.95) of FastAPI. I have tried several ways to implement it but I am facing an error `"AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'get'"`. This implies that the starlette `Request` object is not recognised as such when using `Depends`.

Endpoint implementation:

```py
@app.get("/")
async def home(user: Annotated[User, Depends(authenticate_request(Request))]):
    """
    status _summary_
    Returns status message if service is running
    """
    if isinstance(user, User):
        return {"Welcome, service is running ok!"}
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="User not authorized!",
    )
```

Function `authenticate_request` checks validity of cookies based on provided Request:

```py
def authenticate_request(request: Request) -> User:
    cookie1 = request.cookies.get("x")
    cookie2 = request.cookies.get("y")
    if cookie1 is not None and cookie2 is not None:
        tenant = get_tenant(request)
        if user := authenticate_cookies(cookie1, cookie2, tenant):
            if not tenant.startswith(user.tenant):
                print("Unauthorized: Token hostname mismatch")
                raise Exception("Token hostname mismatch")
            return user
    print("Unauthorized: please login")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized: please login")
```

This results in error `"AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'get'"`. This implies that the `Request` object is not passed correctly or is not recognised as such.

I then tried to solve this without using `Depends`:

```py
@app.get("/")
async def home(request: Request):
    """
    status _summary_
    Returns status message if service is running
    """
    user = authenticate_request(request=request)
    if isinstance(user, User):
        return {"Welcome, service is running ok!"}
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="User not authorized!",
    )
```

This is working correctly. If no valid cookie is provided a 401 is returned. Based on this I come to the conclusion that my authenticate_request() function is working correctly.

Does anybody know why there is a difference in behaviour between `Depends()` and the alternative solution?

Help is much appreciated!

Regards,
Laurens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`Depends()`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant), you just pass the name of the dependency function within the brackets (i.e., **don't call it** directly, just pass it as a parameter to `Depends()`). As described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#create-a-dependency-or-dependable):

> Let's first focus on the **dependency**.
>
> It is just a function that **can take all the same parameters** that a
> *path operation function* can take.
>
> And it has the **same shape and structure** that all your *path operation
> functions* have.
>
> You can think of it as a path operation function without the
> "decorator" (without the `@app.get("/some-path")`).
>
> And it can return anything you want.

Thus, any other parameters that your dependency function takes, you simply need to declare them in that function and not passing them through `Depends()`. Same applies to the `Request` object. FastAPI will analyze the parameters for the dependency, and process them in the same way as the parameters for a *path operation function* (also known as *endpoint*), including sub-dependencies.

Hence, your endpoint should look like this:

```py
@app.get("/")
async def home(user: Annotated[User, Depends(authenticate_request)]):
    pass
```

and your `authenticate_request` dependency function should be as follows:

```py
def authenticate_request(request: Request) -> User:
    pass
```

#### Additional Information

Instead of a "callable" function, one could also use a Python class instead as a dependency, as [Python classes are also **callable**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1).

One not only can they use a "callable" dependency class, but also [a "callable" instance](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/advanced-dependencies/#a-callable-instance) of that dependency class, which would allow them to initially pass *fixed* content when creating the instance of the class, as well as pass additional parameters and sub-dependencies when the endpoint is called.

The `__init__` method in the example below is used to declare the parameters of the instance that we can use to "parameterize" the dependency (the *fixed* content). FastAPI won't ever touch or care about `__init__`, it is used directly in the code when creating the instance of the class.

The `__call__` method, on the other hand, is what FastAPI will use to check for additional parameters and sub-dependencies, and **this is what will be called to pass a value to the parameter** in your endpoint, when it will later be called.

Hence, in the example below, `fixed_content` is the attribute used to "parameterize" the dependency, while `q` is the additional query parameter to pass a value for, when a client is calling the endpoint.

##### Example

```py
class FixedContentQueryChecker:
    def __init__(self, fixed_content: str):
        self.fixed_content = fixed_content

    def __call__(self, q: str = ""):
        if q:
            return self.fixed_content in q
        return False


checker = FixedContentQueryChecker("bar")


@app.get("/query-checker/")
async def read_query_check(fixed_content_included: bool = Depends(checker)):
    return {"fixed_content_in_query": fixed_content_included}
```

Comment: (and the difference is that `authenticate_request(Request)` will _call_ the `authenticate_request` function right there, giving the `Request` _class_ as an argument - the  `Depends` would in that case try to use the return value from `authenticate_request`.

Comment: @chris, your answer clarified a lot. I was not aware of the specifics of path operations and the difference between _Depends()_ calls and normal function calls where you need to provide function parameters. Your help is much appreciated.