# How to Get the Value of an HTTPBearer Token Passed as Dependency in FastAPI?

Tags: python, jwt, backend, fastapi, bearer-token

Trying to learn the basics of authorisation using java-web-tokens from this [github repository](https://github.com/BekBrace/FASTAPI-and-JWT-Authentication). Reproducing [the relevant part](https://github.com/BekBrace/FASTAPI-and-JWT-Authentication/blob/main/main.py#L71) here for easy reference (comments mine).

```py
@app.post("/posts", dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())], tags=["posts"])
def add_post(post: PostSchema):
    # How to access the token string here? 
    # token:str=JWTBearer() # Will this help?
    # I want something like this
    # print(f'The supplied token is {token}.')
    post.id = len(posts) + 1
    posts.append(post.dict())
    return {
        "data": "post added."
    }
```

The author is using the `JWTBearer` subclass to authorise the specific route with a JWT. But is there a simple way to access the value of the token as a local variable inside the handler function `add_post`?

I am pretty new to the whole authorisation-flow, and this repository is simple enough for me to get the essential parts. So I would appreciate if you answer sticks to the same project structure, just answering the question on how to get the token value *inside* the function, without introducing too many new concepts, or a different library etc.

My technology stack (if important) is

- fastapi 0.103.1
- Python 3.10
- Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I'll let someone else give a definite answer but I think you need to add an argument for the token `post: PostSchema, token: str = Depends(JWTBearer())`

Comment: BTW, when I find these kinds of questions I find it helpful to search github to see how other people have implemented what I'm trying to implement, here's I'd search `dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())]` I usually find  A LOT of people forking the same example repo but sometimes I find someone's custom implementation and it helps understand how it works.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455768/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Daviid, you can move the dependencies from the decorator to the function.

```py
@app.post("/posts", tags=["posts"])
def add_post(post: PostSchema, token: Annotated[str, Depends(JWTBearer())]):
    # How to access the token string here? 
    # token:str=JWTBearer() # Will this help?
    # I want something like this
    print(f'The supplied token is {token}.')
    post.id = len(posts) + 1
    posts.append(post.dict())
    return {
        "data": "post added."
    }
```

You can refer to the example in FastAPI's [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant).

Dependencies in path operation decorators are used when you don't need the return value of a dependency - FastAPI's [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-in-path-operation-decorators/)