# FastAPI raises "TypeError: <generator object get_db at 0x00...> is not a callable object" when passing function to Depends

Tags: python, database, typeerror, fastapi, depends

I get:

> File "C:\PythonProjects\myProject\routers\home.py", line 39, in
>
> @router.get("/home", response_class=HTMLResponse)
>
> ...
>
> raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
> TypeError: <generator object get_db at 0x000002B68FBDB100> is not a
> callable object

**home.py**

```
    from fastapi import Depends, APIRouter, Request
    from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse
    
    from database import SessionLocal, engine
    from models import Base
    
    router = APIRouter()
    templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates", autoescape=False)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    
    
    def get_db():
        try:
            db = SessionLocal()
            yield db
        finally:
            db.close()

@router.get("/home", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def all_skills(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db())):
    all = db.query()
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request, "show": all})
```

**database.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQL_ALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/DatabaseName"

engine = create_engine(SQL_ALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

import models
from database import engine
from routers import home
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles


app = FastAPI()

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

app.include_router(home.router)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to use as dependency

```
@router.get("/home", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def all_skills(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    all = db.query()
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request, "show": all})
```

instead of

```
@router.get("/home", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def all_skills(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db()):
    all = db.query()
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request, "show": all})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't call function you want to use as dependency:

```
Depends(get_db)
```

instead of

```
Depends(get_db())
```

Answer (score 2):

As per FastAPI's [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant):

> You only give `Depends` a single parameter.
>
> This parameter must be something like a function.
>
> You **don't call it** directly (don't add the parenthesis at the end),
> you **just pass it as a parameter to** `Depends()`.
>
> Whenever a new request arrives, FastAPI **will take care of**:
>
> - Calling your dependency ("dependable") function with the correct    parameters.
> - Get the result from your function.
> - Assign that result to the parameter in your path operation function.

Hence, in your example, you **shouldn't** be calling the `get_db()` function directly, as you have been doing:

```py
@router.get("/home", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def all_skills(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db())):
    pass                                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Instead, **just pass it as a parameter to** `Depends()` (i.e., `Depends(get_db)`):

```py
@router.get("/home", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def all_skills(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    pass
```

For further details, I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455768/17865804) as well.