# How can I have a FastAPI dependency fill in a path parameter?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi, starlette

I am using FastAPI and I want having two routes that reference the same function. I need the value in one of the cases to come from the path operation, while in the other case, I need it to be generated as a dependency.

Below is what I thought would work, but the `/inbound` case generates a `422 Unprocessable entity` error.

```py
def middleware():
    return {"wako_id": "123"}

def test(request: Request, wako_id: str):
    return wako_id

authorized_router.add_api_route(
  "/inbound",
  test,
  dependencies=[Depends(middleware)],
  methods=["GET"]
)

authorized_router.add_api_route(
    "/outbound/{wako_id}",
    test,
    methods=["GET"]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the `wako_id` parameter declared as `Optional` in the dependecy function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) for more details and examples on optional  parameters in FastAPI), then [check the raw url path of the request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72239186/17865804), and if it is the `/outbound` one, return the `wako_id` value specified by the user, else if the `/inbound` route was called return your custom `wako_id`.

Note that you could also have an `else` statement and return `JSONResponse(content="wako_id is missing", status_code=400)` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details on how to return JSON from FastAPI), in case the `/outbound` route was called without passing the `wako_id` parameter. However, in your case, you don't have to do this, as the  `wako_id` is declared as `path` parameter, and path parameters are always **required** in FastAPI (you can't have optional path parameters—you may find helpful posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528465/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804)). Hence, if the user sent a request to, for instance, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/outbound` (without including the `wako_id` path parameter, e.g., `/outbound/some_str_id_here`), FastAPI would automatically return a `{"detail":"Not Found"}` error response.

Finally, I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455768/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597764/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651246/17865804), in order to better understand how to use `Dependencies` in FastAPI, as well as how to pass an object or a value from a `dependency` function to an endpoint, in case you used a global `dependency` for the entire router or a specific route, using the `dependencies` argument (similar to the example you provided). Otherwise, you could use the `Depends` keyword on the parameter in your endpoint, and return the object/value, as shown in the example below.

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, APIRouter, Depends
from typing import Optional

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()


def get_wako_id(request: Request, wako_id: Optional[str] = None):
    path = request.scope['root_path'] + request.scope['route'].path
    if wako_id and path == '/outbound/{wako_id}':
        return wako_id
    elif path == '/inbound':
        return '123'


def endpoint(wako_id: str = Depends(get_wako_id)):
    return wako_id


router.add_api_route("/inbound", endpoint, methods=["GET"])
router.add_api_route("/outbound/{wako_id}", endpoint, methods=["GET"])
app.include_router(router)
```